# How to stop the connection when HTTP error fetching URL occurred

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to use jsoup to connect via HTTP basic authorization.

The "HTTP error fetching URL" occurred if I gave the wrong value of parameters user and password.

and then the connection keep running even through exceeded the timeout...

Thus the `thandler.sendMessage()` method will never execute.

How can I stop the connection in this situation?

Here's my code :

```
String url = "http://domain/data.xml";
String header = "user_name:password";
String base64_header = new String(Base64.encode( header.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT ));

thread = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect( url )
                                                .header( "Authorization" , "Basic " + base64_header )
                                                .timeout( 10000 )                                                                                                                       
                                                .execute();

            if( response.statusCode() == 200 )
                thandler.sendMessage( thandler.obtainMessage( updateUIwithParsedData ) );
            else
                thandler.sendMessage( thandler.obtainMessage( stop ) );
        }
        catch( IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
thread.start();
```

Can anyone help me plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your `sendMessage(stop)` call into your catch section. Otherwise on error, nothing is stopping your thread.

Better yet, use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and leave the thread handling to Android.